# POST http://localhost:3000/updateSurvey 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, fetch

I am trying to update a collection in mongoDB after the user finishes some tasks. However, whenever I attempt to save the information and update mongo, I'm getting the error `POST http://localhost:3000/updateSurvey/634124db6f 400 (Bad Request)`. Any ideas why my code isn't functioning correctly?

Backend js script

```
app.post('/updateSurvey', async (req, res) => {
try {
    await client.connect();
    var db = client.db('Admin_Db');
    var collection = db.collection('Survey');

    await collection.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": ObjectId(req.body.id)}, {completion: req.body.completion});
    res.send("updated");
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).send(error);
}
});
```

Main.js (this is how I am fetching the data from mongo)

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/updateSurvey", {
method:'POST', 
headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
body: JSON.stringify({id: surveyID, completion: true})})
.then(response=>{response.text()})
.catch(function(err){console.log("Fetch Problem: " + err)});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a route `http://localhost:3000/updateSurvey/634124db6f` exposed on your server. Therefore the 404 error. Since you are using a post call, just pass the `surveyID` in your body when making the post call using fetchAPI instead of sending it as a query param.

And make sure `http://localhost:3000/updateSurvey` is the route to which your are sending your data, without the surveyId in the URL.

**Edit**

Edits made as per request received in comments.

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": id)}, {completion: req.body.completion});
```

should be:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": new ObjectId(id))}, {completion: req.body.completion});
```

_id is of type ObjectId in MongoDB. You are passing id as string. This should most likely be the error from what I can gather by the code shared in your question. You can cast a string to ObjectId by using the ObjectId class provided by the Mongo Driver for node. Even mongoose provides this class.

Comment: I made the changes you specified, but it's still giving me the same POST 404 error. I updated the code to show my changes.

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/updateSurvey 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: So, it's a 400 and not a 404. This means that the API request has been recognised and routed to the appropriate URL. David, 400 errors can happen for several reasons. Is this error coming from the try-catch block in the controller? If so, then its to do with the implementation inside the controller. Share the server console.log(error) in the question.

Comment: So based on my debugging, the issue is coming from the line await collection.findOneAndUpdate(). If I console log the id and completion value just before that line, it appears appropriately. However, I can't seem to figure out the issue. I am not getting any errors, aside from the POST 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I think I might have found the issue. I've updated the answer. Try it out and see if it works now.

Comment: Hey, I made the change but I'm still getting the error. Is it possible that mongo could be the issue not the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231085/discussion-between-tom-bombadil-and-david).